# How to run an C++ Windows form application at the same time with some other c++ code

Tags: c++, winforms, opencv

I'm creating a Windows form application. But now I come across some problems. I want to run the application as well as other code at the same time.

Background information:

I want to make an Open CV image processing program that work together with a Windows form. I want to send the obtained information to the form as well as in the opposite direction.

But the problem is that the "cout" is not executed until the form is closed. I hope you can help me.

Here is my Main.cpp File:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main() {
   Application::EnableVisualStyles();
   Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   TrackingGUI::MyForm form;
   Application::Run(% form);
   cout << "test" << endl; //This line will execute when the form is closed
}
```

Comment: `Application::Run(gcnew TrackingGUI::MyForm());` starts the message loop and initializes the starting Form. What is executed after if the Form's constructor. After that the GUI is shown. If you want to *talk* the another Process, do that in `MyForm.h` (or a method called from there).

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your answer. My other code contains a while true loop. Is this also possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible, not directly. A Windows Forms app is not a Console app. A `while(true)` loop executed in the main Thread will block the whole GUI entirely. You need a worker thread for that, and `Invoke()` / `BeginInvoke()` the main thread (to update the UI with the output you get - with an *intelligent* threshold).

Comment: @Jimi Is there a way to have 2 separate programs talk to each other? As in the open cv program and the form application.

Comment: Yes, of course. Then, it depends on how the other program *talks*. But don't ask me about OpenCV, I only use the .Net port, EmguCV, in C#.

Comment: @Jimi Okay! Thank you very much for the information! I'll do some more research on that!